# How do I prove the following?

Tags: convergence-divergence

The following questions showed up in my high school math textbook and I am unsure how to approach it.

Considering the sequence of partial sums {Sn} given by

$Sn = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$

a) Show that for all positive integers n

$S_{2n} \ge S_n + \frac{1}{2}$

b) Hence prove that the sequence $S_n$ is not convergent.

Comment: It's quite easy. Write the sum for $2n$ as sum of two parts: 1 to n and n+1 to 2n. And then estimate.

Comment: @5Arbiter Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

For part a) observe that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k} \geq \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{2n} = \frac{1}{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Part b) is easy ?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Note that

$$S_{2n} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}+ \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k}=S_{n}+\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k}$$

and

$$\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k}\ge n\cdot \frac1{2n}=\frac12$$

Then suppose $S_n\to L$.

Answer (score 0):

For part (a):

$$
S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}
$$
for n = N,
$$
S_N = \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{k}
$$
for n = 2N
$$
S_{2N} = \sum_{k=1}^{2N} \frac{1}{k} = \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{k} + \sum_{k=N+1}^{2N} \frac{1}{k} >\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{k} ..............(1)
$$
Now let's check n=1 and n=2:
$$
S_1 = \sum_{k=1}^1 \frac{1}{k} = 1  ..............(2)
$$
$$
S_2 = \sum_{k=1}^2 \frac{1}{k} = 1 + \frac{1}{2} ..............(3)
$$
From (1), (2), and (3); by induction:
$$S_{2n} \ge S_n + \frac{1}{2}$$

For part (b), $S_n$ is monotonically increasing function as seen in part (a) (a.k.a harmonic series). Henece, it diverges to infinity.

Comment: Also $$
S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2}
$$ is monolitically increasing but converges.

Comment: That is true, I was wrong,